# Python + BeautifulSoup: Cannot find the contact page from a specific website

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to find the contact page from different websites using Python and BeautifulSoup library. The logic I used is finding the  tags which contain different variations of the keywork '**contact**' and try to extract the link from there using this logic

```
contact_links = soup.find_all('a', text=re.compile(r'(contact|kontakt)', re.IGNORECASE))
```

or

```
contact_links = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'(contact|kontact)', re.IGNORECASE))
```

Although it works on many cases, there are a few where it does not find the page, one of the examples being this website: https://www.teleflex.com/usa/en/

Do you have any idea why it's not working?

**EDIT:**

I found that it's possible using Selenium, adding this:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)
html_content = browser.page_source
print(html_content)
soup_1 = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
contact_links_1 = soup_1.find_all('a', text=re.compile(r'(contact|kontakt)', re.IGNORECASE))
```

While I was able to actually to find an url, it seems that it's not working all the time as the **findAll** method does not find this element:

```
<a title="Contact form" href="https://reigjofre.com/en/contact/">Contact form
```

from the **htmlContent** variable that I used for this website: https://reigjofre.com/en/.

Comment: The page is using javascript to load the elements, beatifulsoup cannot handle that, you need something with an actual webdriver. You can verify this by visiting the page with your browser and turning off javascript.

Comment: So basically you are saying that it's not 100% possible to extract the information from any website, if it's using JavaScript, is that right?

Comment: No, it's very much possible, just not with requests + beautifulsoup, but with other libraries it is. Seems that requests actually has a counterpart these days, requests_html that can do the job. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/how-can-i-scrape-a-page-with-dynamic-content-created-by-javascript-in-python.

Comment: I found a way to do it using Selenium (I edited my initial question) but it's not fully working when I try to find the <a> tag inside the rendered content of the page, which indeed has the Contact element there.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the page is doing additional requests from Javascript to load header/footer. To get the links you can use:

```py
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = [
    "https://www.teleflex.com/usa/en/includes/USA_EN_header.html",
    "https://www.teleflex.com/usa/en/includes/USA_EN_footer.html",
]

for u in urls:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(u).content, "html.parser")
    contact_links = soup.find_all(
        "a", href=re.compile(r"(contact|kontact)", re.IGNORECASE)
    )
    print(contact_links)
```

Prints:

```
[<a class="" href="/usa/en/contact/north-america/">Contact</a>]
[<a class="" href="/sea/en/contact/asia-pacific/">Asia Pacific</a>, <a class="" href="/usa/en/contact/north-america/index.html">CONTACT</a>]
```

Comment: Very nice, but is there a way to find the header or footer when we are running the code or we can only check it manually like you did above? I'm asking because we can have the same issue in a different website and the whole point was to automate this process as much as possible.

Comment: @BR4TO92 Every web-page is different so you need to figure out by yourself where the page is storing the data/making the requests. Thats hard to automate.